# How to create a Python endpoint that uses Datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore, protorpc

I am trying to use create a Python endpoint for an Android and eventually ios application to store data in datastore, but I am having trouble understanding how it all fits together.

I know I want to have 3 entities `User`, `Event`, and `Message`. In my application I want to be able to be able to query, insert, and update a `User`. Event's will be handled as an "update" to a `User` entity. Then I also want to be able to query and insert the messages for the said `User` which is why I am not using `GCM` exclusively.

My `User` entity currently looks like this:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    email = ndb.StringProperty()
    first_name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    last_name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    prof_pic = ndb.BlobProperty(indexed=False)
    status = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    location = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    friends = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True, indexed=False)
    repeating_events = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True, indexed=False)
    non_repeating_events = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True, indexed=False)
```

My `Event` entity looks like this:

```
class Event(ndb.Model):
    start_time = ndb.StringProperty()
    end_time = ndb.StringProperty()
    color = ndb.StringProperty()
    isRepeating = ndb.BooleanProperty()
```

and my `Message` entity looks like this:

```
class Message(ndb.Model):
    message_to = ndb.KeyProperty()
    message_from = ndb.KeyProperty()
    text = ndb.KeyProperty()
```

I think I have an okay understanding of `datastore` and a general understanding of how an `endpoint` is supposed to work. I coded this all in Java once before but have decided to go with Python due to the slow start up time and general buggyness of `AppEngine` in Java. That being said I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how this all fits together with my android application since I am not very confident with Python.

In the example tick tack toe application that was provided they used the `ProtoRPC` messaging library to I think communicate between the `endpoint` and `datastore` but I don't really understand how that works at all and can't actually get my adaptation to be error free since `User` contains a list of `User`'s.

My question is if, why, where, and how the ProtoRPC library should be used.

Comment: The description is solid, but can you be specific about the question ? Is it setting up of an endpoint ? or performing some task ? or abour exchange responses and protorpc?